# how to encode a paragraph for use in a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am completely new to python and struggling to make a simple thing work.

I am reading a bunch of information from a Web service, parsing the results, and I want to write it out into a flat-file. Most of my items are single line items, but one of the things I get back from my Web service is a paragraph. The paragraph will contain newlines, quotes, and any random characters.

I was going to use the CSV module for python, but unsure of the parameters I should use and how to escape my string so the paragraph gets put onto a single line and so I am guaranteed all characters are properly escaped (especially the delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `csv.writer` setup should handle this properly.  Here's a simple example:

```
import csv

myparagraph = """
this is a long paragraph, with "quotes" and stuff.
"""

mycsv = csv.writer(open('foo.csv', 'wb'))
mycsv.writerow([myparagraph, 'word1'])
mycsv.writerow(['word2', 'word3'])
```

This yields the following csv file:

```
"
this is a long paragraph, with ""quotes"" and stuff.
",word1
word2,word3
```

Which should load into your favorite csv opening tool with no problems, as a having two rows and two columns.

Comment: ah, that's easy! it doesn't matter that the resulting CSV file shows up on multiple lines? i was expecting to see an escape \n

Comment: I'm getting this error now: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03b3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: search Stackoverflow for "[python] csv UnicodeEncodeError" ... if that and the Python documentation for csv don't help you, start another question.

Comment: Not sure if its right, but I ended up adding .encode('utf-8') to the strings before writing them to the CSV. Thanks.

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: That's OK if the consumer of the CSV files is expecting UTF-8 or can detect it & handle it. Very important: Excel is NOT such a consumer!

Comment: @John Machin: Thanks for the tip. I will be reading the files myself (into mySql and with another python script)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special.  The CSV module takes care of the quoting for you.

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO()
>>> w = csv.writer(s)
>>> w.writerow(['the\nquick\t\r\nbrown,fox\\', 32])
>>> s.getvalue()
'"the\nquick\t\r\nbrown,fox\\",32\r\n'
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> r = csv.reader(s)
>>> next(r)
['the\nquick\t\r\nbrown,fox\\', '32']
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with setting your expectations, the following is executable pseudocode for how the quoting etc works in the de-facto standard CSV output:

```
>>> def csv_output_record(input_row):
...     delimiter = ','
...     q = '"' # quotechar
...     quotables = set([delimiter, '\r', '\n'])
...     return delimiter.join(
...         q + value.replace(q, q + q) + q if q in value
...         else q + value + q if any(c in quotables for c in value)
...         else value
...         for value in input_row
...         ) + '\r\n'
...
>>> csv_output_record(['foo', 'x,y,z', 'Jack "Ripper" Jones', 'top\nmid\nbot'])
'foo,"x,y,z","Jack ""Ripper"" Jones","top\nmid\nbot"\r\n'
```

Note that there is no escaping, only quoting, and hence if the quotechar appears in the field, it must be doubled.